# Chrome inspector console does not work with version 54.0.2840.99

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I use node-inspector to debug JS with Chrome version 54.0.2840.99.
I enter `"node-inspector"` in one windows cmd console and `"node --debug-brk l:\dev\debug\test.js"` in another windows cmd console. Open `"http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858"` in Chrome. It's able to debug as usual. But I input `"1 + 2"` in Chrome console, press `"Enter"`, nothing happen. I would expect `"3"` is output to Chrome console. It did work with Chrome version 48.0.2564.116. I did not test with other Chrome versions.

Is it a defect of the new Chrome versions? How to resolve the problem?
I captured the pictures as below:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: As you can see https://crbug.com/661613 is WontFix so to convince the developers you'll need to prove it's their fault by [providing a bisect log](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) that would identify the cause. Or simply install a working version of Chrome.

Comment: I saw that bug. I can not believe it is marked WontFix. Everything works well with previous versions of Chrome 54. Is it not regression of Chrome 54? I can not believe.

Comment: The protocol within Chrome can change over time. As said in the issue, file a bug report with `node-inspector` as it is not a Chrome issue. Recently the Chrome team has been working on native Node debugging. Might be worth checking out that work and see if it works for you.

Comment: Does the software development need to consider backward compatibility?

Comment: I understand the change in Chrome may be reasonable. But  does the software development need to consider backward compatibility?  Avoid regression once a product is released to user. I'm using CEF 31.0.1650.57. It works well all the time before updating to Chrome 54. Sometimes, it is expensive to update the CEF components for big products. Any way to resolve this problem without updating CEF components? I also found node-inspector has the same issue with Chrome 54, just took node-inspector for example.

Comment: Same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083622/chrome-console-doesnt-work-for-variables-in-node-inspector-browser-ui-how-to-e

Comment: It's caused by Chrome 54 deprecating `KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by Chrome deprecating [KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyIdentifier).

The workaround would be to add `keyIdentifier` back to the `KeyboardEvent` prototype.

I also noticed that the `KeyboardEvent.key` string values are different from those from `KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier` so I show below how to handle those differences if needed.

```
Object.defineProperty(KeyboardEvent.prototype, 'keyIdentifier', {
    get: function() {
        switch (this.key) {
            case "ArrowDown":
                return "Down";
                break;
            case "ArrowLeft":
                return "Left";
                break;
            case "ArrowRight":
                return "Right";
                break;
            case "ArrowUp":
                return "Up";
                break;
            case "Tab":
                return "U+0009";
                break;
            case "Escape":
                return "U+001B";
                break;
            default:
                return this.key;
        } 
    }
});
```

Simply replacing `isEnterKey()` is not sufficient and the above code handles this fix.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround, as suggested [here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/951#issuecomment-262441472), by [trojanliu](https://github.com/trojanliu) would be editing **DOMExtension.js** file, changing the `isEnterKey()` function...

```bash
vi /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/front-end/platform/DOMExtension.js 
/isEnterKey
```

... to check for the `keyCode === 13`:

```js
function isEnterKey(event) {
  //suit for event.keyIdentifier
  return (event.keyCode !== 229 && event.keyIdentifier === "Enter") || event.keyCode === 13;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This workaround should work for node-inspector. What about the workaround for old cef?

Comment: This will only fix the enter key. It will not fix tab-complete, arrow keys, etc. Please see the other answer for a fix that handles all of these scenarios.