# Chrome console doesn't work for variables in node-inspector browser UI. How to enable?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector, node-debugger

Steps to reproduce.

1. Filename is `index.js` and its contents:

   ```
   'use strict';

   debugger;
   let a = 10; // doesn't mean anything in regards to the issue.
   ```
2. Run `node-debug` against the file.

   ```
   $ node-debug index.js
   Node Inspector v0.12.8
   Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 to start debugging.
   Debugging `index.js`

   Debugger listening on [::]:5858
   ```
3. It opens UI in Chrome and the execution is stopped on `debugger` line.
   Set a watch variable `process` in a `Watch Expression` section. It is possible to examine it easily here. But only here, in `Watch Expression` section.

[image: process_index js - google chrome 2016-12-11 13 17 07]

4. Now try to examine `process` variable in console. It doesn't work. You can type a variable, but hitting `[Enter]` key doesn't reveal `process` variable. It just adds new lines:

[image: process_index js - google chrome 2016-12-11 13 25 46]

What behavior is this? How to make it work?

Comment: The convention here if you solve your own question before anyone else has solved it for you is that you either delete your question or you post an answer to your own question.  Putting `[SOLVED]` in the title is not how things are supposed to work here.  An accepted answer indicates the question is solved and using that mechanism lets people search for questions that don't yet have an accepted answer or see from among all the answers which one the OP accepted.  If you're going to leave your question here, that's how you should use stack overflow.

Comment: Or, if another question/answer provides an answer to your question, then you can also mark yours as a duplicate of that other question - though I'd probably just delete the question myself rather than clog things up with more dups unless your question adds something new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome inspector console does not work with version 54.0.2840.99](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562563/chrome-inspector-console-does-not-work-with-version-54-0-2840-99)

Comment: @jfriend00, Deleting a duplicate question shouldn't be an option. My case is a perfect example. We both experienced the same issue but in a different way. And names of questions are different. So deleting a question may result that somebody won't be able to solve their similar issue in the future skipping the question with different name and context. Anyhow thanks for the info. Sure thing I want to leave my question here so that I could return to it in future.

Comment: @jfriend00 What will happen if I click `[That solved my problem!]` button? My question will be deleted? Closed? Anything else?

Comment: If you click the green checkmark, it just shows the checkmark and indicates to the community that your question has been answered.  If it's not your own answer, then both you and the answerer will earn some reputation points. Your question and all answers remain.  Nothing disappears.  I'm surprised with 4,248 points accumulated here you weren't aware of how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is solved here:
[Chrome inspector console does not work with version 54.0.2840.99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562563/chrome-inspector-console-does-not-work-with-version-54-0-2840-99)

Also, a thread from GitHub about the issue:
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/951#issuecomment-262441472